# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. That has already been passed in the headers

Tags: node.js, express, axios, cors

After adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to the headers of my Axios request, I still get the same error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://backendUrlEndPoint' from origin
> 'https://frontendURL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I've used cors as my middleware in the express server.

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

I'm using Axios for API call

```
const onClickHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const res = await axios.post("http://backendUrlEndPoint", userDetails, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
        });
        console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to configure on `server`, the issue is with missing header in response not request

Comment: @HarshitRastogi I'm having similar issue. It's not for all the front-end platforms i.e Web, Mobile apps. But just for some devices like HTML player or some less known browsers . If you could explain this a bit more.

Comment: @HarshitRastogi and even check the response header, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", is allowed for all.

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

With that config you can omit axios third argument

```
{
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  }
}
```

There must be a problem on server side. With simple server config everything works flawlessly

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.post("/post", function (req, res) {
  res.json({ msg: "ok" });
});
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('App listening at http://localhost:5000}');
});
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So there must be a problem somewhere else. Are you working on localhost or remote adresses ?

Comment: I've deployed my backend on Heroku and using frontend on localhost as well as on remote, both give the same error.